# Error in converting images to LIst<Asset> in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the File type of converted images to List but getting the below error

```
 for (int i = 0;i < widget.image.length;i++) {
   var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
     widget.image[i].identifier);
     print("path");
     print(path);
     File compressedFile =await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(path, 
     quality: 90);
     final List<Asset> image=compressedFile;
     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
     Share_Convert_Iamge(image: image)),
   );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You converted one file, it is not a list of images. If you try to load this image to a widget, you can try to use `Image.file`:

```dart
Image.file(
  compressedFile,
);
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```dart
final List<File> images = [];
for (int i = 0;i < widget.image.length;i++) {
  final path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
    widget.image[i].identifier,
  );
  File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
    path, 
    quality: 90,
  );
  images.add(compressedFile);
}
```

And convert it to list:

```dart
images.map((imageFile) => Image.file(imageFile)).toList();
```

Comment: its a list of images

Comment: thank you for answer but i want List<Asset>

Comment: i want list of List<Asset> not List<File>

Comment: When you converted an image you do not getting an image, you get a file.

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I can see, you want to create a list of images. So, if my assumption is correct, you should do the following:

```
final List<File> images = List<File>();
 for (int i = 0; i < widget.image.length;i++) {
   var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(widget.image[i].identifier);
     print("path");
     print(path);
     File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(path, quality: 90);
     images.add(compressedFile);
     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
     Share_Convert_Iamge(image: images)),
   );
```

Now, I don't exactly understand your question. But what you were doing wrong was this:
the variable "image" is of type "List" which means that it holds a list of objects of type "Asset".
But the variable "compressedFile" is of type "File". Now, just like you cannot assign a float value to a variable of type integer, for example:

```
// This will give you an error.
int x = 12.56;

// This will work.
float x = 12.56;
```

So, the error is just a case of type-mismatch.

Now, if you want to display the image somewhere, you can use the following Widget:

```
Image.file(file_variable)
```

Here, file_variable is of type "File".

Comment: @JanviPatel use the code suggested by me. It will allow you to use the list of files (images, in this case).

Comment: it creates an error in final List<File> images; this line it must be initialized error comes

Comment: @JanviPatel I have made a slight change, this should help.

Comment: but i want List<Asset> so that i can show images in next page in listview

Comment: But I don't think you require the images as Asset. You can have it as File and still use it. If you don't mind, can you share the code where you're displaying the images?

Comment: I don't have AnyDesk but I am willing to help you. So, if you'd like to add me to the GitHub repository only temporarily, please do so. My GitHub ID:
www.github.com/preetshah21699

Comment: @JanviPatel, you have uploaded a zip file. I would recommend you to upload the entire folder instead. I've downloaded the files and will let you know what can be done.

Comment: Use Image.file(widget.image[index]) wherever you would like to show the image.

Comment: @JanviPatel if you try the Widget I have suggested in the answer, it will work. Once it works please upvote the answer.

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems. You should try small things. After that move on to other things. If I simply give you the answer, you won't be able to learn.